# is there any way to stick on the same page even after refreshing in react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

Hi am new to react and facing a problem in react router . Actually am using useNavigate in react router dom for navigation and everything is working fine but my problem is suppose initially i am on page one then using useNavigate in am reaching to page two then from page two to page 3. Now when am refreshing the page everything is getting started with page 1 again but,  what i want  is if am on page 3 then on refreshing must be on page 3 is there any way to achieve it.

for example i am using two pages (my goal is if i am on 2nd page on refresh i must be on 2nd page) but for current situation browser is starting from first page

i am writing my first page like this

```
import react from "react";
import "../../../../css/panel/articleverificationpanel/topmostTray.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

class MainLoginAreaForPanel extends react.Component {
  goButtonClicked =() => {
    try {
      const userId = document.getElementById("userId").value;
      const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
      const securityKey = document.getElementById("securityKey").value;
      console.log(userId, password, securityKey);
      const data = {
        userId,
        password,
        securityKey,
      };
      axios
        .post(
          `http://localhost:4000/app/panel/articleverification/signin`,
          data
        )
        .then((res) => {
          // means file has been uploaded
          if (res.data.success === 1) {
            console.log(this.props)
            this.props.authorizeUser(true,{})
            this.props.navigation('/panel/articleverification/homepage',{replace:true})
            
          } else {
            throw new Error('Sorry could not verify you');
          }
          
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert(error.message);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <react.Fragment>
        <div id="mainLoginPanelArea">
          <label htmlFor="userId" className="children">
            User id:
          </label>
          {"   "}
          <input type="text" id="userId" name="userId" className="children" />
          <br />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          {"   "}
          <input type="text" id="password" name="password" />
          <br />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="securityKey">Security Key:</label>
          {"   "}
          <input type="text" id="securityKey" name="securityKey" />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <button className="btn" onClick={this.goButtonClicked}>
            GO
          </button>
        </div>
      </react.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

// Wrap and export
export default function(props) {
  const navigation = useNavigate();

  return <MainLoginAreaForPanel {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
}
```

this is how i am writing my second page

```
import react from "react";
import TopmostTrayForPanel from "./topmostTray";
import CardForPanel from "./cardForPanel";
import {Navigate,useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from "axios";

class HomePageForArticalVerificationPanel extends react.Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
  };
  openArticle = (articleId) => {
    this.props.navigation('/panel/articleverification/articlepage',{replace:true,state:
      {articleId:articleId}
    })
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("loaded");
    this.getUnverifiedArticles();
  }
  
  getUnverifiedArticles() {
    let data = [];
    let cnt = 0;
    let temp = [];
    axios
    .get(
      `http://localhost:4000/app/panel/articleverification/getunverifiedarticles`,
      data
    )
    .then((res) => {
      
      console.log(res)
      if (res.data.success === 1) {
        const articles = res.data.data.articles 
        for (let i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
          if (cnt > 2) {
            data.push(<div className="row" key={`extra${i}`}>{temp}</div>);
            cnt = 0;
            temp = [];
          }
          if (cnt <= 2) {
            temp.push(
              <div className="col-sm" key={i}>
                <CardForPanel title={articles[i].title} tags={articles[i].tags} aid={articles[i].aid} openArticle={this.openArticle}></CardForPanel>
              </div>
            );
            cnt++;
          }
          
        }
        if(temp.length !=0){
            data.push(<div className="row" key={`last one`}>{temp}</div>);
        }
        this.setState({
          data: data,
        });
      } else {
        throw new Error('Sorry could not verify you');
      }
      
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error.message);
    });
    
  }
  render() {
    if (this.props.authorized) {
      return (
      
        <div className="parent_container">
          <TopmostTrayForPanel></TopmostTrayForPanel>
          <div className="container">{this.state.data}</div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Navigate to='/panel/articleverification'  />
      )
    }
    
  }
}

// Wrap and export
export default function(props) {
  const navigation = useNavigate();

  return <HomePageForArticalVerificationPanel {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
}
```

and below is my routing code

```
import React from "react";

import {Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import EditorPage from './components/editor/classbased/editorPage'
import LoginPageForArticalVerificationPanel from './components/panel/articleverficationpanel/classbased/loginPage'
import HomePageForArticalVerificationPanel from './components/panel/articleverficationpanel/classbased/homePage'
import ArticlePageForArticalVerificationPanel from './components/panel/articleverficationpanel/classbased/articlePage'
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    authorised:false,
    extras:{}
  }

  authorizeUser = (authorizeState,extras) => {
    console.log('called 1')
    this.setState({
      authorised:authorizeState,
      extras:extras
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/editor' element={<EditorPage />} />
            <Route path='/panel/articleverification' element={<LoginPageForArticalVerificationPanel authorizeUser={this.authorizeUser}/>} />
            <Route path='/panel/articleverification/homepage' element={<HomePageForArticalVerificationPanel authorized={this.state.authorised}/>} />
            <Route path='/panel/articleverification/articlepage' element={<ArticlePageForArticalVerificationPanel authorized={this.state.authorised}/>} />

        </Routes>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see. Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what the code is doing and possibly say why anything is "resetting" upon a page refresh.

Comment: Are these two components rendered by any `Route` components? Do you have some checks that happen when the app mounts that redirects anywhere? Can we also see the routing/navigation code?

Comment: @DrewReese added routing code also

Comment: yeah these both are rendered by route component

Comment: Is path `'/panel/articleverification'` the "first page" and path `'/panel/articleverification/homepage'` or `'/panel/articleverification/articlepage'` the "second" and/or "third" pages? You are on one of these nested paths and refresh the page and get redirected back to `'/panel/articleverification'`? I suspect the `authorised` state is reset and the page component you are on is redirecting back.

Comment: @DrewReese you guess correct about the pages order and you are also correct that after refresh i am redirecting back to '/panel/articleverification' but can you tell me how i can stop authorised state being getting reset on page refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, after navigating to one of the nested routes and reloading the page, the app reloads and the `authorized` state is reset and the child route component checks this state and imperatively redirects back.

Persist and initialize the `authorized` state to/from localStorage.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    // Read initial state from localStorage, provide fallback
    authorized: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authorized")) ?? false,
    extras: {}
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // Persist authorized state changes to localStorage
    if (prevState.authroized !== this.state.authorized) {
      localStorage.setItem("authorized", JSON.stringify(authorized));
    }
  }

  authorizeUser = (authorizeState, extras) => {
    console.log('called 1');
    this.setState({
      authorized: authorizeState,
      extras: extras
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/editor' element={<EditorPage />} />
        <Route
          path='/panel/articleverification'
          element={(
            <LoginPageForArticalVerificationPanel
              authorizeUser={this.authorizeUser}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path='/panel/articleverification/homepage'
          element={(
            <HomePageForArticalVerificationPanel
              authorized={this.state.authorized}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path='/panel/articleverification/articlepage'
          element={(
            <ArticlePageForArticalVerificationPanel
              authorized={this.state.authorized}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Routes>
    );
  }
}
```